# ZFS Heavy Write Amplification due to Free Space Fragmentation

Tags: raid, postgresql, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have setup ZFS RAID0 for PostgreSQL database. The Storage and Instances are in AWS EC2 and EBS volumes.

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
pgpool   479G   289G   190G         -    70%    60%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
  xvdf  59.9G  36.6G  23.3G         -    71%    61%
  xvdg  59.9G  34.7G  25.2G         -    70%    57%
  xvdh  59.9G  35.7G  24.2G         -    71%    59%
  xvdi  59.9G  35.7G  24.2G         -    71%    59%
  xvdj  59.9G  36.3G  23.6G         -    71%    60%
  xvdk  59.9G  36.5G  23.4G         -    71%    60%
  xvdl  59.9G  36.6G  23.3G         -    71%    61%
  xvdm  59.9G  36.6G  23.2G         -    71%    61%
```

Previously the `FRAG` is at 80% on most of the devices and we have suffered a heavy write IOPS. As the pool capacity is previously at 75% utilization (400GB), provisioned additional 10GB to each device (400GB + 80GB). Now the `FRAG` is reduced to 70%. One important metric is that write IOPS is much lesser for the same workload now.

[image]

As per the Cloudwatch metrics after increase in EBS size, write IOPS drastically reduced to 1200 - 1400 IOPS from 4000 IOPS for Master PG and reduced to 600 IOPS from 3000 IOPS for Slave PG. I have suspected that this is due to how `FRAG` amplifies writes as explained in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/556892/376277).

We have set `recordsize=128K` as the `compressratio` is much better than `recordsize=8K`. I think due to higher `recordsize`, `FRAG` is increased quickly and results in write amplification and heavy write IOPS. Will decreasing the record size would prevent write amplification or any other problem which I am missing?

**Database Info**

```
PostgreSQL 9.6
Checkpoint Timeout: 10min
Total Databases: ~1100
Tables / DB: ~1300
Files / DB: ~6000 to 8000 (1300 Tables + Indexes + Toast)
Total Files for All DBs: ~7.7m
```

In average for every 5 mins, ~60000 to 70000 files (Tables + Indexes + Toast) would be affected (as per postgres checkpoint completion log). So any tuning need to be done regarding the huge number of files? Or atleast what I'm hoping is why the drastic difference in IOPS when additional space is added to the pool?

Also I've seen the same kind of IOPS difference a month back when additional space is added to the pool but getting back to the high IOPS rate after two days. So I guess the same would repeat after two to three days and that's why I'm suspecting Free Space Fragmentation `FRAG` would be the culprit..!!

**ZPOOL Props**

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-59:~$ sudo zpool get all
NAME    PROPERTY                       VALUE                          SOURCE
pgpool  size                           479G                           -
pgpool  capacity                       60%                            -
pgpool  altroot                        -                              default
pgpool  health                         ONLINE                         -
pgpool  guid                           1565875598252756833            -
pgpool  version                        -                              default
pgpool  bootfs                         -                              default
pgpool  delegation                     on                             default
pgpool  autoreplace                    off                            default
pgpool  cachefile                      -                              default
pgpool  failmode                       wait                           default
pgpool  listsnapshots                  off                            default
pgpool  autoexpand                     on                             local
pgpool  dedupditto                     0                              default
pgpool  dedupratio                     1.00x                          -
pgpool  free                           190G                           -
pgpool  allocated                      289G                           -
pgpool  readonly                       off                            -
pgpool  ashift                         0                              default
pgpool  comment                        -                              default
pgpool  expandsize                     -                              -
pgpool  freeing                        0                              -
pgpool  fragmentation                  71%                            -
pgpool  leaked                         0                              -
pgpool  multihost                      off                            default
pgpool  feature@async_destroy          enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@empty_bpobj            enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@lz4_compress           active                         local
pgpool  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@spacemap_histogram     active                         local
pgpool  feature@enabled_txg            active                         local
pgpool  feature@hole_birth             active                         local
pgpool  feature@extensible_dataset     active                         local
pgpool  feature@embedded_data          active                         local
pgpool  feature@bookmarks              enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@filesystem_limits      enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@large_blocks           enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@large_dnode            enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@sha512                 enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@skein                  enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@edonr                  enabled                        local
pgpool  feature@userobj_accounting     active                         local
```

**ZFS Props**

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-59:~$ sudo zfs get all
NAME    PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
pgpool  type                  filesystem             -
pgpool  creation              Mon Oct  8 18:45 2018  -
pgpool  used                  289G                   -
pgpool  available             175G                   -
pgpool  referenced            288G                   -
pgpool  compressratio         5.06x                  -
pgpool  mounted               yes                    -
pgpool  quota                 none                   default
pgpool  reservation           none                   default
pgpool  recordsize            128K                   default
pgpool  mountpoint            /mnt/PGPOOL            local
pgpool  sharenfs              off                    default
pgpool  checksum              on                     default
pgpool  compression           lz4                    local
pgpool  atime                 off                    local
pgpool  devices               on                     default
pgpool  exec                  on                     default
pgpool  setuid                on                     default
pgpool  readonly              off                    default
pgpool  zoned                 off                    default
pgpool  snapdir               hidden                 default
pgpool  aclinherit            restricted             default
pgpool  createtxg             1                      -
pgpool  canmount              on                     default
pgpool  xattr                 sa                     local
pgpool  copies                1                      default
pgpool  version               5                      -
pgpool  utf8only              off                    -
pgpool  normalization         none                   -
pgpool  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
pgpool  vscan                 off                    default
pgpool  nbmand                off                    default
pgpool  sharesmb              off                    default
pgpool  refquota              none                   default
pgpool  refreservation        none                   default
pgpool  guid                  571000568545391306     -
pgpool  primarycache          all                    default
pgpool  secondarycache        all                    default
pgpool  usedbysnapshots       0B                     -
pgpool  usedbydataset         288G                   -
pgpool  usedbychildren        364M                   -
pgpool  usedbyrefreservation  0B                     -
pgpool  logbias               throughput             local
pgpool  dedup                 off                    default
pgpool  mlslabel              none                   default
pgpool  sync                  standard               default
pgpool  dnodesize             legacy                 default
pgpool  refcompressratio      5.07x                  -
pgpool  written               288G                   -
pgpool  logicalused           1.42T                  -
pgpool  logicalreferenced     1.42T                  -
pgpool  volmode               default                default
pgpool  filesystem_limit      none                   default
pgpool  snapshot_limit        none                   default
pgpool  filesystem_count      none                   default
pgpool  snapshot_count        none                   default
pgpool  snapdev               hidden                 default
pgpool  acltype               off                    default
pgpool  context               none                   default
pgpool  fscontext             none                   default
pgpool  defcontext            none                   default
pgpool  rootcontext           none                   default
pgpool  relatime              off                    default
pgpool  redundant_metadata    most                   local
pgpool  overlay               off                    default
```

**ARC**

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-59:~$ cat /proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats
13 1 0x01 96 4608 8003814189 8133508755293587
name                            type data
hits                            4    48883641586
misses                          4    1321425301
demand_data_hits                4    15606800719
demand_data_misses              4    786648720
demand_metadata_hits            4    32729793033
demand_metadata_misses          4    278006868
prefetch_data_hits              4    315020107
prefetch_data_misses            4    207366277
prefetch_metadata_hits          4    232027727
prefetch_metadata_misses        4    49403436
mru_hits                        4    10685966527
mru_ghost_hits                  4    85159850
mfu_hits                        4    37807765384
mfu_ghost_hits                  4    40046050
deleted                         4    960331018
mutex_miss                      4    15489677
access_skip                     4    17626
evict_skip                      4    21812713742
evict_not_enough                4    267500438
evict_l2_cached                 4    0
evict_l2_eligible               4    108797848903680
evict_l2_ineligible             4    2000957528064
evict_l2_skip                   4    0
hash_elements                   4    313401
hash_elements_max               4    769926
hash_collisions                 4    587807552
hash_chains                     4    11108
hash_chain_max                  4    6
p                               4    3794526616
c                               4    7022898344
c_min                           4    1004520576
c_max                           4    16072329216
size                            4    6944858120
compressed_size                 4    3732648960
uncompressed_size               4    20043857408
overhead_size                   4    1682603008
hdr_size                        4    110128312
data_size                       4    3359916544
metadata_size                   4    2055335424
dbuf_size                       4    246193488
dnode_size                      4    943126912
bonus_size                      4    230157440
anon_size                       4    33360384
anon_evictable_data             4    0
anon_evictable_metadata         4    0
mru_size                        4    3718656000
mru_evictable_data              4    1940126208
mru_evictable_metadata          4    224441856
mru_ghost_size                  4    1684268032
mru_ghost_evictable_data        4    0
mru_ghost_evictable_metadata    4    1684268032
mfu_size                        4    1663235584
mfu_evictable_data              4    1288254464
mfu_evictable_metadata          4    83499008
mfu_ghost_size                  4    1506922496
mfu_ghost_evictable_data        4    1391591424
mfu_ghost_evictable_metadata    4    115331072
l2_hits                         4    0
l2_misses                       4    0
l2_feeds                        4    0
l2_rw_clash                     4    0
l2_read_bytes                   4    0
l2_write_bytes                  4    0
l2_writes_sent                  4    0
l2_writes_done                  4    0
l2_writes_error                 4    0
l2_writes_lock_retry            4    0
l2_evict_lock_retry             4    0
l2_evict_reading                4    0
l2_evict_l1cached               4    0
l2_free_on_write                4    0
l2_abort_lowmem                 4    0
l2_cksum_bad                    4    0
l2_io_error                     4    0
l2_size                         4    0
l2_asize                        4    0
l2_hdr_size                     4    0
memory_throttle_count           4    0
memory_direct_count             4    3209752
memory_indirect_count           4    15181019
memory_all_bytes                4    32144658432
memory_free_bytes               4    6916120576
memory_available_bytes          3    6413860864
arc_no_grow                     4    0
arc_tempreserve                 4    0
arc_loaned_bytes                4    0
arc_prune                       4    252427
arc_meta_used                   4    3584941576
arc_meta_limit                  4    12054246912
arc_dnode_limit                 4    1205424691
arc_meta_max                    4    12420274128
arc_meta_min                    4    16777216
sync_wait_for_async             4    4231322
demand_hit_predictive_prefetch  4    195199007
arc_need_free                   4    0
arc_sys_free                    4    502260288
```

**zdb -C**

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-59:~$ sudo zdb -C pgpool

MOS Configuration:
        version: 5000
        name: 'pgpool'
        state: 0
        txg: 4739409
        pool_guid: 1565875598252756833
        errata: 0
        hostname: 'ip-10-0-1-59'
        com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
        vdev_children: 8
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 1565875598252756833
            create_txg: 4
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 1507251152420866879
                path: '/dev/xvdf1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 64
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1425
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 129
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 130
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 12461793154748882472
                path: '/dev/xvdg1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 68
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1424
                create_txg: 9
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 131
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 132
            children[2]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 2
                guid: 15169312858460766498
                path: '/dev/xvdh1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 69
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1427
                create_txg: 12
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 133
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 134
            children[3]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 3
                guid: 8533762672700299025
                path: '/dev/xvdi1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 74
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1422
                create_txg: 15
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 71
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 72
            children[4]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 4
                guid: 6612366135198079494
                path: '/dev/xvdj1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 139
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1428
                create_txg: 18
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 136
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 137
            children[5]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 5
                guid: 15947515837120747219
                path: '/dev/xvdk1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 142
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1421
                create_txg: 21
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 140
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 141
            children[6]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 6
                guid: 15626684534009192025
                path: '/dev/xvdl1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 146
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1426
                create_txg: 24
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 143
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 144
            children[7]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 7
                guid: 19815078749163274
                path: '/dev/xvdm1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 149
                metaslab_shift: 27
                ashift: 9
                asize: 64418480128
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1423
                create_txg: 27
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 147
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 148
        features_for_read:
            com.delphix:hole_birth
            com.delphix:embedded_data
```

**zfs.conf**

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-59:~$ sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf
options zfs zfs_arc_max=77147180237
```

**zdb metaslabs & spacemap**

[zdb -m / -mm / -mmm](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GlunVx4V-2tGu5FeL6D7jrvFiICULHK9?usp=sharing)

From the metaslabs and spacemap info, it look like the metaslabs and spacemaps at end of each vdev have lots of free space (due to latest size expansion) compared with the upper regions. So this correlates with the problem explained [here](https://zfs.datto.com/2017_slides/sproul.pdf) as how the degrade in performance when the metaslabs and spacemap is fragmented.

I think it's better to add mirrors and remove the old vdevs so to promote the new devices as primary stripe. This would help the metaslabs and spacemap as if it's a fresh pool without much fragmentation (??? not sure !!!). Anyway, this would be kept as a last resort, until then I'll look into verifying the problem nature and any tunings needed regarding metaslabs / spacemap from zfs side.

Also to reduce fragmentation, planned to add zfs log device to a seperate device and moving postgres pg_xlog directory to seperate device with ext4 partition.

Comment: It's unclear why you're stating that you're facing write amplification. What is even more important, is what ashift your pool is running with, and what is the native block size of the block devices it's built upon. The latter is probably non-determineable for EBS. Also, at this point I highly doubt that iops dropoff was caused only by increasing device size, considering you weren't hitting the 80% pool utilization threshold, where all the capacity/gangblock performance penalties usually happen.

Comment: @drookie I can strongly say that the IOPS drop was only after increasing device size and not by any other factors. Yes, 80% pool utilization threshold is not reached but the `FRAG` is at 80% when IOPS was high. So I'm suspecting that heavy free space fragmentation might cause write amplification.

Comment: Well you cannot do anything about space fragmentation because this is the COW-fs nature. On the other hand your pgpool should not suffer from it because the usual load profile for RDBMS is random-read/random-write, unless your load mostly comprises fullscans or you're serving large BLOBs.

Comment: Its also worth remembering that setting the record size to 128k doesnt mean the records will be 128k, thats just the maximum they will be. Therefore once it has been set its probably worth doing some analysis of what they actually are and what the mode writes size is. I saw an article a while ago (cant lay my hands on it at the moment) that stated they found a happy medium for them was 32k. Yes you get some write amplification, but most of their writes were bigger than than 8k, so it wasnt an issue.

Comment: However setting the max record size to 8k forced their normal writes IOPS to quadruple or worse, as generally they were not really small. 

Therefore the rule seems to be, set it to 128k initially, and run some tests. After which you can see the block size trends. Once you have the optimal block setting you can then either just change the setting, and let the data migrate over time, or copy the data to a new dataset with the record size set (might not work for large datasets)

Comment: What are your /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf settings?

Comment: @ewwhite updated the /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf content

Comment: Oh, you need tuning.

Comment: @ewwhite included database and no of files info. Any links related to tuning you're speaking of..?

Comment: @drookie Our use case is very unique as we have huge number of files and thousands of files changed every 5 mins. You could the see the database info I've included. Our database is more of writes than reads as it's for archival / backup purpose but with the ability to query whenever needed (infrequent for now)

Comment: @krad included database and no of files info. Any ideas related to that?

Comment: @krad included database and no of files info. Any ideas related to that?

Comment: Your record size is inefficient for databases. Change it to 8k.

Answer (score 4):

Without deep debug, it is difficult to give you a definitive answer. Anyway, some things to note are:

- ZFS allocate blocks via [spacemaps.](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/space-maps) When a spacemap is >= 96% full (80% for older build), ZFS will switch from first-fit to best-fit allocator. Note that this is a per-spacemap decision: you can have an 80% full pool with some spacemaps well over that value, maybe already at over 96%. When writing to such spacemaps, ZFS will use the slower best-fit allocator
- a fragmented spacemap will use much more memory than a non-fragmented one. This added memory pressure can lead to [spacemap trashing.](https://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg45408.html) You can avoid that by setting [`metaslab_debug_load=1`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/ZFS-on-Linux-Module-Parameters#metaslab_debug_load); if it does not work, try re-importing your pool and/or setting [`metaslab_debug_unload=1`.](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/ZFS-on-Linux-Module-Parameters#metaslab_debug_unload) Note that persistently locking all spacemaps in memory will inevitably consume more RAM
- you could be burned by [gang blocks](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/solaris/ZFSGangBlocks) but, again, it is difficult to tell if it is the case without further debug. Surely a 128K recordsize, with such a good `compressratio`, is doing you no favor with regard to fragmentation. You can read some more information [here](https://thomas.gouverneur.name/2011/06/20110609zfs-fragmentation-issue-examining-the-zil/) and [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/5h8oqw/at_what_percentage_does_a_zfs_zpool_become/)

Side note: I see your pool has `ashift=9`. I think that pure 512B devices are quite rare nowadays, especially in cloud environment. In a bid to increase performance, you can/would re-create your pool with `ashift=12`.

Comment: From the metaslabs and spacemap info I've included now, seems like spacemap fragmentation might be the cause. I'll check on tuning for those.